# AsyncTask: Pass an exception value from doInBackground to onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i am trying to pass an error message between my doInBackground into my onPostExecute. Would there be any way to do this using data structures? In my situation i'm am trying to avoid making a class and returning an object

```
                    @Override
        protected User doInBackground(List<Pair<String, String>>... params) {
            randomAPI api = randomAPI
                    .getInstance(context);

            try {
                **thing that will generate error**
                }

            } catch (RandomException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            }
            return somethingThatIsUsableInOnPostExecute;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User result) {

            }
```

Comment: You can put member variables inside of the Asynctask like any other class

Comment: What I just said is unrelated to Asynctask. It's a class like any other Java class. Do you not know how what a "member variable" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String exception = "";
@Override
    protected User doInBackground(List<Pair<String, String>>... params) {
        randomAPI api = randomAPI
                .getInstance(context);

        try {
            **thing that will generate error**
            }

        } catch (RandomException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
            exception = e.getMessage();
        }
        return somethingThatIsUsableInOnPostExecute;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(User result) {
            if(!exception.isEmpty()){
                //exception path
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer if it helps you ! Thank you!

Comment: i think you should initialize exception = "" every time in doInBackground.

Answer (score 1):

> you should try to change `return` type of  `doInBackground` from
>   `User` object to `Object` and cast it in `onPostExecute`.